# Tensorflow model having different behavior with functionally identical model code

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been working on creating a CNN machine learning model to analyze types of brain tumors. Using Kaggle I found a dataset and code for an already created model (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/masoudnickparvar/brain-tumor-mri-dataset). The code looked like it used an outdated data pipeline, so I used the keras.utils.image_dateset_from_directory to create my own dataset to use for the model. However, when I train my model and use it, it overfits and predicts the same value for every type of brain scan even though the model says it has a validation accuracy of 90%. The code from Kaggle, however, works flawlessly and is able to predict well. Could someone help me spot the difference and find out if my model does not work and the other one does? I suspect it has something to do with my data pipeline.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

BATCH_SIZE = 20
IMG_SIZE = 128
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("C:\\data\\MRI Images\\Training",
                                                  labels="inferred",
                                                  color_mode="rgb",
                                                  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                  seed=123,
                                                  image_size = (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),
                                                  subset = "training",
                                                  validation_split = 0.2
                                                  )

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("C:\\data\\MRI Images\\Testing",
                                                  labels="inferred",
                                                  color_mode="rgb",
                                                  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                  seed=123,
                                                  image_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)
                                                  )
data_augmentation = Sequential(
  [
    
    layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)),   
    layers.RandomBrightness(0.2),
    layers.RandomContrast(0.2),
    layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
  ]
)

model1 = Sequential([
  data_augmentation,
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
  layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

base_model = VGG16(input_shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3),weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
base_model.layers[-2].trainable = True
base_model.layers[-3].trainable = True
base_model.layers[-4].trainable = True
model = Sequential([
    data_augmentation,
    base_model,
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'],
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001))

epochs=5
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  epochs=epochs,
)
model.summary()
print(model.evaluate(val_ds))
model.save("Originaltf.h5")
```

Kaggle Code:

```
# For Data Processing
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

# For ML Models
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.losses import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras.applications import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img

# For Data Visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Miscellaneous
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import random

train_dir = "C:\\data\\MRI Images\\Training"
test_dir = "C:\\data\\MRI Images\\Testing"

train_paths = []
train_labels = []

for label in os.listdir(train_dir):
    for image in os.listdir(train_dir+"//" +label):
        train_paths.append(train_dir + '//'+label+ '//'+image)
        train_labels.append(label)

train_paths, train_labels = shuffle(train_paths, train_labels)

IMAGE_SIZE = 128
def augment_image(image):
    image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image))
    image = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image).enhance(random.uniform(0.8,1.2))
    image = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image).enhance(random.uniform(0.8,1.2))
    image = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(image).enhance(random.uniform(0.8,1.2))
    image = np.array(image)/255.0
    return image

def open_images(paths):

    images = []
    for path in paths:
        image = load_img(path, target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
        image = augment_image(image)
        images.append(image)
    return np.array(images)


images = open_images(train_paths[50:59])
labels = train_labels[50:59]

unique_labels = os.listdir(train_dir)

def encode_label(labels):
    encoded = []
    for x in labels:
        encoded.append(unique_labels.index(x))
    return np.array(encoded)

def decode_label(labels):
    decoded = []
    for x in labels:
        decoded.append(unique_labels[x])
    return np.array(decoded)

def datagen(paths, labels, batch_size=12, epochs=1):
    for _ in range(epochs):
        for x in range(0, len(paths), batch_size):
            batch_paths = paths[x:x+batch_size]
            batch_images = open_images(batch_paths)
            batch_labels = labels[x:x+batch_size]
            batch_labels = encode_label(batch_labels)
            yield batch_images, batch_labels

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
'''
model = build_model()
model.fit(datagen(train_paths, train_labels, batch_size=32, epochs=10), steps_per_epoch=len(train_paths)//32, epochs=10)
model.save("basic.h5")
'''
base_model = VGG16(input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
# Set all layers to non-trainable
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
# Set the last vgg block to trainable
base_model.layers[-2].trainable = True
base_model.layers[-3].trainable = True
base_model.layers[-4].trainable = True

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,3)))
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(len(unique_labels), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
'''
batch_size = 20
steps = int(len(train_paths)/batch_size)
epochs = 5
history = model.fit(datagen(train_paths, train_labels, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs),
                    epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps)

model.save("transf.h5")
'''
model.summary()
```

Comment: have you tried debugging and/or testing your data pipeline since you suspect it might be the problem, and it is, from what i can see, deterministic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "deterministic"? I'm not sure what to look for when it comes to it, but I know all the images load in and are labeled correctly.

Comment: i'm contrasting it with the model. Models are typically non-deterministic (e.g. due to randomness), probabilistic and with emergent properties, which makes unit testing and debugging a lot harder. The data prep doesn't have that problem so unit tests are feasible there, to make sure the images are reaching the model correctly.

Comment: The problem could be with the provided dataset. There may be an `imbalanced dataset` for each class or could have less data to train the model. You need to provide almost the same amount of data for each class. You can also try by providing a default `learning rate(0.01)` for `Adam` Optimizer and by increasing the number of epochs. Please mention the subset="validation" in val_ds set. Also, Please follow the methodologies mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#strategies_to_prevent_overfitting) to avoid model overfitting.